# Strange python error

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program that calculates a histogram, given a list of numbers like:

```
1
3
2
3
4
5
3.2
4
2
2
```

so the input parameters are the filename and the number of intervals.

The program code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys, re, string, array, math
import numpy

Lista = []

db = sys.argv[1] 
db_file = open(db,"r")
ic=0
nintervals= int(sys.argv[2])

while 1:
    line = db_file.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    ll=string.split(line)
    #print ll[6]
    Lista.insert(ic,float(ll[0]))
    ic=ic+1

lmin=min(Lista)
print "min= ",lmin
lmax=max(Lista)
print "max= ",lmax

width=666.666
width=(lmax-lmin)/nintervals
print "width= ",width

nelements=len(Lista)
print "nelements= ",nelements
print " "
Histogram = numpy.zeros(shape=(nintervals))

for item in Lista:
    #print item
    int_number = 1 + int((item-lmin)/width)
    print " "
    print "item,lmin= ",item,lmin
    print "(item-lmin)/width= ",(item-lmin)," / ",width," ====== ",(float(item)-float(lmin))/float(width)
    print "int((item-lmin)/width)= ",int((item-lmin)/width) 
    print item , " belongs to interval ", int_number, " which is from ", lmin+width*(int_number-1), " to ",lmin+width*int_number
    Histogram[int_number] = Histogram[int_number] + 1
```

4

but somehow I am completely lost, I get strange errors, can anybody help¿

Thanks

P.D. These are the results of the output:

```
item,lmin=  1.0 1.0
(item-lmin)/width=  0.0  /  0.666666666667  ======  0.0
int((item-lmin)/width)=  0
1.0  belongs to interval  1  which is from  1.0  to  1.66666666667

item,lmin=  2.0 1.0
(item-lmin)/width=  1.0  /  0.666666666667  ======  1.5
int((item-lmin)/width)=  1
2.0  belongs to interval  2  which is from  1.66666666667  to  2.33333333333

item,lmin=  3.0 1.0
(item-lmin)/width=  2.0  /  0.666666666667  ======  3.0
int((item-lmin)/width)=  3
3.0  belongs to interval  4  which is from  3.0  to  3.66666666667
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "from_list_to_histogram.py", line 43, in <module>
    Histogram[int_number] = Histogram[int_number] + 1
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

The most important errors are:

(item-lmin)/width=  1.0  /  0.666666666667  ======  1.5

and

IndexError: index out of bounds

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Never use `while 1: f.readline()`. Use `for line in f:`.

Comment: Don't use `string.split`. Use the split method of the `str`/`unicode` type.

Comment: Don't name variables with uppercase first letters. People will be confused when they aren't classes.

Comment: Don't use `insert` to put something at the end of a list. Use the `append` method.

Comment: Always use `with open(filename, mode) as f:` to ensure the file gets closed no matter what.

Comment: What is the purpose of fractional buckets?

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for all the help, I will start to learn just now from all of your very useful comments. the only thing that just surpeises me really now is why did I get -2 votes. i know that I am not a python guru and that my question was kinda stupid, but ithink that sites like SO are just for this, for putting question when people get blocked, so they can learn from all the other people's experience. thanks a lot

Comment: @Werner: I'll guess that you got down votes because of the #1 comment -- "what errors are you getting?"  You still have not answered the question.  What errors are you getting?  What doesn't work?  Please be specific.

Comment: @Mike_Graham: can you give me an example of the str/unicode type? (instead of string.split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed code that loads from file and rewrite to something more readable

```
from math import floor

Lista = [1,3,2,3,4,5,3.2,4,2,2]
ic=0
nintervals= 3

lmin=min(Lista)
print "min= ",lmin
lmax=max(Lista)
print "max= ",lmax

width=1.0*(lmax-lmin)/nintervals
print "width= ",width

nelements=len(Lista)
print "nelements= ",nelements
print " "
histogram =[0]*nintervals

for item in Lista:
    ind = int(floor(1.0*(item-lmin)/width))
    if ind==nintervals:
        ind=ind-1
    histogram[ind]+=1

for i,v in enumerate(histogram):
    print "from", lmin+i*width, "to", lmin+(i+1)*width, "are",v,"values"

for i,v in enumerate(histogram):
    print "Visual presentation:","="*int(round(v*40.0/lmax))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem may be a peculiar off-by one in the line:

```
int_number = 1 + int((item-lmin)/width)
```

Why that `1 +`?  Python indices on an array of length N are from 0 to N-1 included.  The `1 +` here makes int_number go from 1 to `1 + (lmax-lmin)/width` i.e. to `1 + nintervals` given the formula for `width`, while you've sized `Histogram` to `nintervals` items -- so it's actually an off-by-two, worsened by the `1 +` but it would be there (for lmax only) even without it. make the intervals an epsilon wider, so lmax falls inside the last one and not just beyond it, and lose the `1 +`, and things might work better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more Pythonic approach.

```
from itertools import groupby
from math import floor

data = [1,3,2,3,4,5,3.2,4,2,2,3.6]
data.sort()

nintervals = 3
lmax = max(data)
lmin = min(data)

width = 1.0*(lmax-lmin)/nintervals

def grouper(item):    
    return floor(1.0*(item-lmin)/width)

for i, b in groupby(data, grouper):
    print '%.3f <= i < %.3f ' %(lmin + i * width, lmin + (i+1) * width), list(b)
```

Comment: Don't use `floor(1.0*(item-lmin)/width)`. Use `(item - lmin) // width)`. (It's sort of funny that you went through the trouble of premultiplying by 1.0 to get float division rather than floor division when it ends up you really did want floor division. ;) I typically prefer `from __future__ import division` or calling `float` to get float division, which I believe are more idiomatic.)

Answer (score 0):

On the last line you access Histogram with a too big index. You should make sure that 'int_number' is at most

```
len(Histogram) - 1
```

There's probably a bug, which causes this problem.